# How to show when $V$ is a vector space, $V-V=V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space. Show that $V-V=V$ where $V-V:=\{x-y\,\,\, :\,\,\, x \in V, \,\,\, y \in V\}$.

We need to prove $V-V \subseteq V$ and $V \subseteq V-V$. The first one is straight forward. I have problem with the second one.

My try:
Let $w, z \in V$ we need to show $w= x_1 -y_1 $ and $z= x_2 - y_2$ for some $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in V$.

Comment: Well, it's straightforward as it is $z = x-y = x + (-y) \in V$ and that $z \in V$ can span the whole space.

Comment: My problem is finding a way that shows $w,z$ can be decomposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z$ be a vector in $V$.

$z = z+0 =z+(y+(-y))=(y+z)-y=x-y$ for some $y\in V$. Therefore, $y-x \in V-V$. Hence, $z \in V-V$.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need two vectors? Let $v\in V$. Then $v=v-0\in V-V$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but using the above $y=0$ for any element and we have $V \subseteq W= \{x-y \mid x \in V, y=0\}$.

Comment: What does it mean to show that $V\subseteq V-V$? We need to show that any element in $V$ is also an element in $V-V$, which means that if $v\in V$ then there are $x,y\in V$ such that $v=x-y$. And we indeed can take $x=v,y=0$. So $v\in V-V$. Ok, it is true that we can take the same $y$ for any vector. But it doesn't change the fact that we showed that every vector in $V$ is a difference between some two vectors in $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v \in V$ then $v = v - 0$ and since $V$ is a vector space, both $v$ and $0$ are in $V$ so then $V \subseteq V-V$.

Answer (score 0):

$ V = V - \{0\} \subseteq V - V \subseteq V$, so they must all be equal.

(You might have to think a bit about that middle inclusion, but it's just an instance of the very general fact that if $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are arbitrary subsets of $V$ with $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$, then $A-C \subseteq B-D$ .)

Comment: Can you define your $A,B,C, D$

Comment: Sure. Answer updated.

Comment: By the way, if you are still struggling with vector spaces this answer might be a bit too brief, as it kind of assumes away some of the details that you are writing out. But I thought I'd provide it anyways, as I rather like it, and its style of argument, showing things are equal with a chain of inclusions that has the same thing at the far left and far right, can be used in lots of other places so it's worth seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $V$ is a vector space **iff** $tV \subset V$ for all $t$ and $V+V \subset V$.

In particular, with $t=-1$ we have $-V  \subset V$ and multipliying across by $-1$ gives
$V \subset -V$ hence $V=-V$.

Furthermore, $V=2V \subset V+V \subset V$, so $V=V+V$.

Combining gives $V=V-V$.